# Linking Groups of Data with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

what I'm trying to accomplish is an easy way to maintain HTML data during changes.

For example, if I have 10 div images with let's say a Christmas picture in each and I have to change each div's image to the theme of a Holiday when it occurs.  Now, doing it manually by changing  into  would be fine but what if I had 100 images I needed to change?
Is there a way to have the div images point to an array with the pictures in it or a file with the images?  By doing so, I could just name the image  and it would just point to the file and extract the image from there and all I would need to do is change the file from time to time (i.e. File name is named HolidayPics, when I need to replace that file with another, I would rename the newer file the SAME name and rename the older HolidaysPics to HolidaysPicsOld or something for use later").

I'm trying to achieve this using JSON.

The images are all stored in a file and the json file is as follows

```
{
"boximages": [
    {
        "url": "boximages/1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url": "boximages/2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url": "boximages/3.jpg"
    },
    {
        "url": "boximages/4.jpg"
    }
      {
        "url": "boximages/5.jpg"
    }
      {
        "url": "boximages/6.jpg"
    }
      {
        "url": "boximages/7.jpg"
    }
      {
        "url": "boximages/8.jpg"
    }
      {
        "url": "boximages/9.jpg"
    }
      {
        "url": "boximages/10.jpg"
    }

]
}
```

Comment: you could create variable directories/paths and change them based on the Date(). Within each directory is the set of images for the season.

Comment: Uh... That's a very general question that depends on a million factors of how you're loading the image. If you're using some framework, you can pretty easily configure a way to determine certain aspects of the page by creating a table in your DB that you can manage through some admin site. If you're configuring these things using CSS, you might want to use something like LESS maybe and then configure images and stuff as variables, changing them manually every so often. But what you really want to do is focus your question a little bit so we understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pgu87to7/6/

Comment: @Stuart Yes, something like that!  I guess I should forget using Json because it seems I need a server for that?  I'll try manipulating your code around...I don't need the buttons, just the images to display

Comment: As an out-of-the-box solution: Why don't you change the name of the folder containing the 100 images? Or (if the images are not stored locally and under your control): use a fixed JSON format with 'currentboximages/1.jpg' etc, and replace the images in the folder on serverside.

Comment: You can (i) store your lists of variables in your main js file (ii) store them in a separate js file preceded by e.g. `var myData = [...` and include that in your html file before your main js script, or (iii) import json using something like jQuery's [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method. None of these require you to set up anything special on the server.